# Ok to use one of the two 12V batteries of a 24V system?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

Coach bus with a 24V system of 2x12V 120Ah batteries for aux load. I need 12V for IT stuff. Is it ok to take it from a single battery or is it a bad idea? Right now I have a crappy 12V->24V converter that I would need to replace if this is a bad idea.

Update: Great answers. Sadly I could pick only one although all 3 are very useful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan using the two 12V batteries again in series, I'd not recommend it. Because you will generate charge asymmetry between the two. The one you use alone will have less charge than the idle one.

So if you plug them back together, the one you used will be depleted earlier than the other one, and even be undercharged by the other battery, which might destroy it.

A way out may be to separately recharge them to 100% after your using one of them, so they are both at the same charge level when being used for the 24V system again.

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a bad idea.

Hooking your... IT stuff to a single battery will discharge it faster than the other, especially if you're planning on using your devices when the engine is off.

If your devices power consumption is low compared to the battery size then you are good to go, but a 24V->12V DCDC converter (that's what you meant, right?) is still the best solution.

If you have multiple devices and you can balance the load between the two batteries that's fair enough too but **keep in mind** that your devices will **not be sharing the same ground**, so connecting them together would probably result in **harmful** (but spectacular) **failures**. Like batteries exploding failures.

Comment: Oh yeah 24->12 converter, yes. My bad.
Also..."IT stuff" is about as vague as you can get :D Thanks for pointing that out. It will have a max load of 200W.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it's generally a Bad Idea as you end up with unequally charged and unequally "worn out" batteries with different internal resistances, I am aware of at least one occasion of someone running this sort of system having a battery explode.

As the system charges by simply putting ~28v across the batteries in series, it's not hard to imagine why there could be an issue if one battery develops a higher internal resistance than the other.

You're best off using a 24->12v converter or a separate 12v battery + 12v alternator for heavy 12v loads.

Comment: Wouldn't he better off with a battery equalizer? It is good to have one anyways for batteries in series, and it would also add lifetime to both batteries.

Comment: A battery equaliser can only do so much for physically mis-matched batteries.

Comment: Yes, but I thought in a 2 battery 24v system, if 12v is drawn from only one of the two batteries, a battery equalizer would fill up whatever was drained by the 12v system.

Comment: It greatly depends how the equaliser works, and cycling one battery like that is not good.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but are equalizers not similar in how they work? I would imagine that if not kuch is drained an equalizer should be able to handle it properly. Also, it is good to have an equalizer even with same age batteries.